# How to push docker-compose.yml in Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, docker-compose, heroku-cli

So I have created a web app which has frontend in react and backend in golang.

The file structure is like this.

```
app
 - client
   - Dockerfile
   - react app files
 - server
   - Dockerfile
   - go files
 - docker-compose.yml
```

I'm able to run `docker-compose up` locally to run the app.

But I'm having problem to push the app into Heroku as it requires `Dockerfile` in root dir.

I don't want to make a single `Dcokerfile`, How do I push the app to Heroku either using `docker-compose.yml` or `heroku.yml`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does Heroku actually support that? Why not get the backend to serve the frontend, then you only have a single dyno.

Comment: Heroku docs mentions two ways to push,
1. using Dockerfile in root dir
2. using Heroku.yml (I'm guessing this can be used with docker-compose.yml)

Not able to find any good examples.